# event.returnValue is deprecated iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've written an iframe to embed into my website however I am constantly getting this  warning: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

I have looked online however nobody mentions any problems with iframes.  Does anyone knows why it is warning about event being deprecated?

My Code is this:

```
<iframe width="984" height="558" frameBorder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHfWtA7AsHI"></iframe>
```

The video is displaying fine but when I check for errors on the page, I get that warning.  If I remove the iframe, error goes away.

Comment: The error is with YouTube. And it isn't an error, just a warning. Inside chrome if you do any mouse events, that error will appear even if you don't returnValue. It's a built in function that's used by Chrome for some other functions.

Comment: That has nothing to do with iframes, but with the page that the iframe loads. Apparently Youtube uses `event.returnValue` somewhere. Nothing for you to worry about. See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=event.returnValue+is+deprecated.+Please+use+the+standard+event.preventDefault%28%29+instead.